# .htaccess Rewrite not working without slash in the end

Tags: .htaccess

I'm with an issue with .htaccess and I hope you can help me out.

Basically I have the following structure:

> root/
>              + _archive
>              + index.html
>              + folder1
>              + folder2
>              + css
>              + ...

On archive I have a few folders that I want it to be accessible through the root of my site.

So let's say my site calls rafael.com, so I would have the following archives:

> http://www.rafael.com/_archive/folder10
>   http://www.rafael.com/_archive/folder20
>   http://www.rafael.com/_archive/folder30

I want them to be accessible from (without _archive):

> http://www.rafael.com/folder10
>   http://www.rafael.com/folder20
>   http://www.rafael.com/folder30

But also having the folders and css, and images and etc on my root to keep working. Keep in mind that under folder10, folder20, folder30 I also can have their own images and css, and javascript.

Well, I'm trying the following .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond $1 ^(folder10|folder20|folder30)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ _archive/$1 [L]
```

and that works fine if I call using http://www.rafael.com/folder30/ (WITH SLASHES IN THE END) my problem is when I try to call http://www.rafael.com/folder30 without the slashes it gets REDIRECT to http://www.rafael.com/_archive/folder30/ .

So can anyone explains to me WHY it's being redirecting it and how do I fix it in order to have http://www.rafael.com/folder30 and http://www.rafael.com/folder30/ working without redirecting it? :)

Thank you in advanced.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have any other rules in place? without an `[R=30x]` flag it shouldn't visibly redirect the url. Also you need to fix your `RewriteCond $1` to something like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^folder(10|20|30)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /_archive/$1 [NC,L]
```